# How to render ggplot chart when button update is pressed?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I would like to have this chart to rerender only when I press on button `updt`. This is the code I have so far

````
---
title: ""
author: 
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    storyboard: true

runtime: shiny
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
actionButton('updt', 'Update chart')
checkboxGroupInput('gear', 'number of gears', unique(mtcars$gear), (mtcars$gear))
observeEvent( eventExpr = input$updt , handlerExpr = {
  renderPlot({
    dd <- mtcars %>% filter(gear %in% input$gear)
    f1 <- ggplot(aes(mpg, disp), data=dd) + geom_point()
    f1
  })

})

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?observeEvent`:

> observeEvent returns an observer reference class object

This can not be plotted.

You could do something like:

```
observeEvent( eventExpr = input$updt , handlerExpr = {
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    dd <- mtcars %>% filter(gear %in% isolate(input$gear))
    f1 <- ggplot(aes(mpg, disp), data=dd) + geom_point()
    f1
  })
})
plotOutput("myplot")
```

but still you have to `isolate(input$gear)` as `output$myplot` is reactive to `input$gear`

So the best is to remove the `observeEvent`, add `req(input$updt)` to make  `renderPlot` reactive to it and `isolate(input$gear)`:

```
renderPlot({
    req(input$updt)
    dd <- mtcars %>% filter(gear %in% isolate(input$gear))
    f1 <- ggplot(aes(mpg, disp), data=dd) + geom_point()
    f1
  })
```

Comment: Thanks, is your solution generally preferable to `observeEvent` or just something you prefer?